# How to create a pipeline of html elements using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to know, it's possible to create a conveyor moving html elements (example div) using jQuery and how do it?

Example:
[image: conveyer]

*(on the shown above rectangles moves left to right; Start to add the new, and the last is removed)*

And then:

```
[7]->[6]->[5]->[4]->[3]->[2]->[1] ([0] - no more; [7] - new)
```

then

```
[8]->[7]->[6]->[5]->[4]->[3]->[2] ([1] - no more; [8] - new)
```

and etc.

The implications of this: a continuous conveyor belt, which supplies html elements for drag and dropping.

Comment: Nice idea! Better start coding. When you have some code, you can come back here and we can help you out.

Comment: Yes it's possible. What have you tried?

Comment: look at jquery carousel plugins

Comment: Test for a job interview? Homework?

Comment: @MelanciaUKneed for simple online game. I'm beginner.

Comment: The question asked is "is it possible using JQuery?", so the correct answer is **"Yes"!** *Please provide some existing effort/code for more information about how.* :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible. You need to remove last child from parent div and append new child to parent div every few seconds.